# Qt Creator - Adding a large amount of values to a Comb Box

Tags: qt, combobox, qt-creator

I have a long list of number (491) and I want to fit them all into a Comb Box widget in Qt Creator. Going in by hand is an option, but I feel as if there is a much more efficient way to go about adding the numbers into the box.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are the numbers stored? Are they in a text file separated by comma or each one in a new line?

Comment: 500 entries in a combobox sounds like awesome user interface.

Comment: Nejat --> .txt file with new lines.

Comment: Osterfeld --> The best.

Comment: @Sluxxy added a solution that includes reading from a textfile into a QStringList and setting it as `QComboBox` Content. Please let me know if anything is not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over your storage container and add them.

```
QComboBox *comboBox;

comboBox = new QComboBox( this );
comboBox ->setGeometry( 100 , 100 , 100 , 20 );

QList< int > intList;

intList.append( 1 );
intList.append( 2 );
intList.append( 3 );
intList.append( 4 );
intList.append( 5 );
intList.append( 6 );
intList.append( 7 );

foreach( const int &i , intList )
{
    comboBox->addItem( "Item: " + QString::number( i ) , i );
}
```

Or did I misunderstand your question?

---

To get the data from the textfile into a QStringList you can just do:

```
    QFile       file( "/path/filename.txt" );
    QStringList stringList;


    if( ( !file.fileName( ).trimmed( ).isEmpty( ) ) &&
        (  file.exists( ) ) && 
        (  file.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text ) ) )
    {
        QTextStream textStream( &file );

        while( !textStream.atEnd( ) )
        {
            stringList << textStream.readLine( );
        }

        file.close( );

    // then just fill the QComboBox Text.
    comboBox->addItems( stringList );
```

Comment: What about adding more values to an existing ComboBox?

Comment: @Sluxxy works the same way except that you don't have to create a new QComboBox object.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but the amount of values was just cut down to just an eighth of the size. Thanks for answering, though. I just won't need it.

Comment: @sluxxy You can still use it even for an eighth if the size